# angularjs child state to get data for parent state

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to implement a child state for getting data to the main state. While I'm in the child state I want to show $ionicLoading content over the view of the parent state and after the data is loaded it should leave the child state and go back to the parent state. How do I implement this using angularjs/ionicframework?

The controller for the state I want to split of is looking like this:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPopover, $state, $ionicLoading, $ionicPlatform, $q, WebService, DBService) {

  //------ THIS PART SHOULD GO INTO THE CHILD STATE -----//
  $ionicLoading.show({
    template: "Daten werden geladen...",
    animation: "fade-in",
    showBackdrop: false,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 500
  });


  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/popover.html', {
      scope: $scope
    }).then(function (popover) {
      $scope.popover = popover;
    });

    DBService.dropTables();

    DBService.createAllTables();

    WebService.getAllTables().then(function(res) {

      $ionicLoading.hide();

      $scope.refreshDestinations();
      //DATA is loaded leave the child state

    }, function(err) {

      $ionicLoading.hide();

      //Change the state to login
      $state.go('app.login');

    });
  });
  //----------- UNTIL HERE  -----------//

  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scope is inherited, so if you want to call a parent scope function from a child can. An example: with ionic loading, if it creates a isolated scope (which it may) you may have to call $parent.$ionicLoading.show().

```
<div class="show-scope-demo">
  <div ng-controller="GreetController">
    Hello {{name}}!
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ListController">
    <ol>
      <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}} from {{department}}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>





 angular.module('scopeExample', [])
    .controller('GreetController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
      $scope.name = 'World';
      $rootScope.department = 'Angular';
    }])
    .controller('ListController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.names = ['Igor', 'Misko', 'Vojta'];
    }]);
```